# Observer pattern update parameters

Tags: java, observable, observer-pattern

Why does the Observer interface has **Observable o** as a parameter?
Do you recommend using Javas existing classes (implements Observer; extends Observable)?

```
  public class Test implements Observer {
  void update(Observable o, Object arg);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

It receives the `Observable` reference so that the `Observer` can use it to address the way it will handle the `Object` arg that was passed. Also, the `Observer` could call `deleteObserver` to remove itself once it finished the job.

You shouldn't use them. And it's not me that's telling you, it's the people behind java themselves. Check it out:

https://dzone.com/articles/javas-observer-and-observable-are-deprecated-in-jd
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

In Java 9,  `Observer` and `Observable` are deprecated.

> Deprecated.  This class and the Observer interface have been
>   deprecated. The event model supported by Observer and Observable is
>   quite limited, the order of notifications delivered by Observable is
>   unspecified, and state changes are not in one-for-one correspondence
>   with notifications. For a richer event model, consider using the
>   java.beans package. For reliable and ordered messaging among threads,
>   consider using one of the concurrent data structures in the
>   java.util.concurrent package. For reactive streams style programming,
>   see the Flow API.

Check out this other answer:
[How observers subscribe on observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614152/how-observers-subscribe-on-observables/47614182#47614182)

Answer (score 0):

If you use this pattern you need both Observer and Observables.

---

```
public class Airport extends Observable {

    private final String name;

    public Airport(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void planeLanded(String flight) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(flight);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DispatcherScreen implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Flight " + arg + " landed at " + o.toString());
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observer screen = new DispatcherScreen();

        Airport airport1 = new Airport("San Francisco International Airport");
        Airport airport2 = new Airport("O'Hare International Airport");
        airport1.addObserver(screen);
        airport2.addObserver(screen);
        //
        airport1.planeLanded("FR1154");
        airport1.planeLanded("UI678");
        airport2.planeLanded("SU1987");
        airport1.planeLanded("UI678");
        airport2.planeLanded("AI4647");
    }

}
```

Comment: Observer and Observable are deprecated in java9. You shouldn't be using them. Only use them to study the pattern.